# Monodroid GC and Sensors

Tags: garbage-collection, xamarin.android, android-sensors

I recently started deploying my test code onto an actual device and ran some sample code provided by Xamarin involving different technologies that they introduce you to. Then I came upon an issue with their garbage collector when trying to test out sensors. With the latest version it runs when you reach a certain threshold however that makes the device unresponsive. Using the code from http://docs.xamarin.com/android/recipes/OS%2f%2fDevice_Resources/Accelerometer/Get_Accelerometer_Readings but just changing it to add 2 more sensors, a gyroscope and gravity sensors, the project lasts about 30 seconds before the GC begins to run. I noticed that every time you reference the e.Values list from the OnSensorChanged function you get more references created. Is there a way to delete those references, as the app I'm working on requires those three sensors and needs to run for about 4 to 5 mins, (its just a section of the app but a really important section).  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link actually provides a way to understand that issue comes up as well as the solution that would fix the issue completely.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1084#c6